# Google Maps flickering issue in Google Chrome browser

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome, browser

In my Javascript Application, Google maps are used with lot of Markers.This Google Map is displayed properly in Browsers Firefox, IE 9, Safari...But in Google Chrome(version 12.0.742.112) when Zoom in and Zoom out the google maps are Flickering...It is not displayed properly...What is the problem here...Please help me to clear this issue...

Comment: please provide example code.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is most likely caused by a conflict with your [hardware acceleration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_acceleration).  Timing

I had the same problem.  I found that by disabling 'Use hardware acceleration when available' option from the Advanced Settings > System options sorted this out for me.

I have done a bit of research and it appears that this bug is fixed in later builds of Chrome.  Hope this is the answer you were looking for!

My issue stemmed from the fact that my graphics card was an NVidia card that has a known bug with some hardware acceleration.

Another option, rather than just disabling Hardware Acceleration entirely, is to turn down your hardware acceleration settings.  See [this link](http://www.wikihow.com/Turn-off-Hardware-Acceleration) which gives instructions how to access the hardware acceleration setting in Windows.  Move the slider down about 2 clicks which should disable any Direct 3D drawing abilities.

Answer (score 1):

Try a different build of chrome (say, chrome canary)and/or disabling hardware acceleration within chrome itself.

Answer (score 0):

On linux I had the problem because, nvidia driver wasn't installed. Once the driver installed the flickering disapear.

Answer (score 0):

Clear all your cookies.

1. List item
2. On your computer, open Chrome.
3. At the top right, click More More and then Settings.
4. At the bottom, click Advanced.
5. Under "Privacy and security," click Content settings.
6. Click Cookies.
7. Under "All cookies and site data," click Remove all.
8. Confirm by clicking Clear all.

More info click [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

This solution worked for me.